# Need some guidance on creating an entry in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface

I am new to cassandra and find it a bit difficult to understand in creating a simple keyspace with some structure that I am thinking of. I created a keyspace called "acquisition" using the cassandra CLI.

Using Cassandra-CLI how can I create the following for the "acquisition" keyspace -

```
TagNo // This is the super column
{
  ID // This is the column family
   {
     // here we shall have lots of entries. (Rows)
     user1: {rate, distance, capacity}
     user2: {rate, distance, capacity}
    }    
}
```

Rate distance and capacity can be stored as either strings or doubles. But does not really matter at the moment.

I am not sure how on to do this using the CLI. So please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- create keyspace.

  > create keyspace acquisition with placement_strategy =
  >   'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' and strategy_options =
  >   {replication_factor:1};
- create super column family.

  ```
  create column family TagNo with column_type = 'Super' and comparator = 'UTF8Type' and subcomparator = 'UTF8Type' and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' and column_metadata = [{ column_name : rate, validation_class : AsciiType}, { column_name : 'distance', validation_class : AsciiType}, {column_name : 'capacity', validation_class : AsciiType}];
  ```
- set a few example values to the TagNo super column family.

  ```
  [default@acquisition] set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user1']['rate'] = '10';
  Value inserted.
  Elapsed time: 2 msec(s).
  [default@acquisition] set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user1']['distance'] = '100'; 
  Value inserted.
  Elapsed time: 2 msec(s).
  [default@acquisition] set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user1']['capacity'] = '50';
  Value inserted.
  Elapsed time: 2 msec(s).
  [default@acquisition] set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user2']['capacity'] = '50';
  Value inserted.
  Elapsed time: 2 msec(s).
  [default@acquisition] set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user2']['rate'] = '20';
  Value inserted.
  Elapsed time: 1 msec(s).
  [default@acquisition] set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user2']['distance'] = '100'; 
  Value inserted.
  Elapsed time: 2 msec(s).
  ```
- show values..

  ```
  [default@acquisition] get TagNo[utf8('ID')];
  => (super_column=user1,
       (column=capacity, value=50, timestamp=1331605812776000)
       (column=distance, value=100, timestamp=1331605805912000)
       (column=rate, value=10, timestamp=1331605780216000))
  => (super_column=user2,
       (column=capacity, value=50, timestamp=1331605816568000)
       (column=distance, value=100, timestamp=1331605846008000)
       (column=rate, value=20, timestamp=1331605821608000))
  Returned 2 results.
  Elapsed time: 3 msec(s).
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. Just a question. To create the ID column family I thought I had to write up a command like 'create colum ID'...  So I assume the command  set TagNo[utf8('ID')]['user1']['rate'] = '10'; will create the column family 'ID' ?

Comment: Welcome, no, the ID is the rowkey for the super column TagNo.

Comment: Wajih, may I ask, the notation TagNo, ID, user1, user2, is that json or what? I'm asking this because I've found confusion on interpreting that notation. Hence then to adapt to cassandra data model.

Comment: Well I am going to be working in C# and read all over the internet about this jsonish notation. So though I should use it here as well.

Comment: I would still love to know how to create the column family.